# Destructuring assignment and null coalescing

Tags: coffeescript

For a singular assignment in CoffeeScript, you can use the existential operator:

```
name = obj?.props?.name
```

This results in a rather lengthy block of code, that checks that `obj` and `props` are defined.

```
name = typeof obj !== "undefined" && obj !== null ? 
    (_ref2 = obj.props) != null ?
    _ref2.name : void 0 : void 0;
```

Consider a more complex, destructuring assignment:

```
{name: name, emails: [primary], age: age} = Person.get(id)
```

If the object contains no `emails` property, that code would throw a `TypeError`. Is there any way to use the existential operator with these kinds of destructuring assignments?

This is the best alternative I have so far:

```
{name: name, emails: emails, age: age} = Person.get(id)
primary = emails?[0]
```

Comment: I don't think so. Destructured assignment is for cases where you know the structure you're dealing with, it isn't a general purpose data structure unpacking and normalizing system. I think you'd be better off modifying `Person` to provide appropriate defaults and apply appropriate data cleanup (i.e. `emails` should always be an array rather than forcing everyone else to differentiate between `undefined`, `null`, `[]`, `['pancakes@example.com']`, ...).

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks. I see your point about defaults. It was just a toy example but nevertheless I'm planning to add `?:`to handle `{emails?: [primary]}` syntax. Coffescript has tons of syntax sugar but somehow it is still not sweet enough for me :)

Comment: not that its any better, but if you don't have access to the `Person` api, then maybe you could do this? http://jsfiddle.net/1av7qbnk/ kinda ugly, I know, but an option anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ES6, you can do this:

```
const {name: name, emails: [primary] = [], age: age} = Person.get(id)
```

If `Person.get(id)` returns an empty object, `primary` will be `undefined` (no `TypeError` is thrown).

The forthcoming CoffeeScript 2 supports this as well, which you can try at http://coffeescript.org/v2/#try

Answer (score 0):

I filed [an issue about this](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3876) back in February. It seems like there is some support for it, but it hasn't been assigned or implemented yet.